# How does the fscanf function work?

Tags: c

Can someone walk me through on how does the `fscanf` work on this particular example (also what EOF represents). The code works, but I don't understand the process behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LEN 20

int main()
{ FILE *in;
  float average;
  char name[LEN];
  char surname[LEN];
  int grade, n_grades; //n_grades is the total number of grades a person has//  

  in = fopen("grades.txt","r");
  if(in == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"error fopen(): Failed to open file grades.txt.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }


   while(fscanf(in,"%s",name) != EOF){
       fscanf(in,"%s",surname);
       n_grades = 0;
       average = 0.0;


       while( !feof(in) && fscanf(in,"%d",&grade)>0 ){
    n_grades++;
    average += grade;
    }


    if(n_grades >0)
        average /= n_grades;
    printf("%s %s %.2f\n", name, surname, average);  
   }
   fclose(in);
   return 0;
}
```

The `grades.txt` looks like this:

```
Steve Stevenson 2 9 4 3 2
John Johnson 2 11 5 3 
Jack Jacskon 22 1 4 5
```

I don't get how this `while` loop works. How does the `fscanf` know exactly which string to read in when? And how does it know when the end of a line is and how to proceed to the next one?

Comment: the code block, beginning with: 'while(fscanf(in,"%s",name) != EOF){' is making the (unsupported.wild) assumption that if a first name is input that all other reads for that line will word correctly.  that is a bad assumption.  a I/O error could occur or the line not be correctly formatted.  Such needs to be allowed for when coding the algorithm.

Comment: regarding this line: 'while( !feof(in) && fscanf(in,"%d",&grade)>0 ){'  1) it is always a bad idea to have 'feof()' as a controlling element in a while statement as it is only set AFTER trying to read past end of file.  2) if each line begun with a number, that number would be read as another grade for the prior student.  strongly suggest reading, in a loop, a whole line via fgets() or getline(), into a buffer, then parsing that buffer with a combination of strtok() to setup each string, strcpy() for first/last name and atoi() for each grade

Comment: regarding this line: 'while(fscanf(in,"%s",name) != EOF){' EOF is not the best way to go.  Rather, use: 'while(fscanf(in,"%s",name) == 1){' as any other returned value indicates an I/O error or EOF  or invalid value in file (note: use 1 because there is 1 input/conversion specifier in the format string)

Comment: the format strings: '"%s"' have a problem.  specifically, there is no length limit specified so a long name in the input file will overflow the input buffer.  suggest using something like: '"%20s"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to focus in the double loop you have there:

```
while(fscanf(in,"%s",name) != EOF){
  fscanf(in,"%s",surname);
  while( !feof(in) && fscanf(in,"%d",&grade)>0 ){
    n_grades++;
  }
}
```

EOF stands for End Of File, so the first loop will continue until the end of the file is found, i.e. until the file pointer reaches the end of the file.

Now remember that your file has data like this: `Steve Stevenson 2 9 4 3 2`.

So the first while will try to read a name, if EOF is not reached yet, that means that you read a name and you assigned it in `name`. Here you read Steve.

Now this `fscanf(in,"%s",surname);` will read the second string from the current row in the file `in` points to (notice the `%s`, which indicates that we expect to read a string). You read Stevenson and you assign it to `surname`.

Then, in the second while, you read until you do *not* reach EOF *AND* until you read integers. If you check the ref of [fscanf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) you will see:

> Return Value
>   On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
>
> If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

So when you read a newline for example, you will have read zero integers, thus you will exit the loop.

That way you will eventually parse all the file.

On the spirit of the example I have [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/fgets-vs-scanf-overflow/) with `scanf()`, you could re-write the code as such:

```
while(fscanf(in,"%19s",name) != EOF) {
```

in order to avoid overflowing. Here 20 is the size of your array.

Comment: So, just to clarify, my in-loop loop `while` runs until the end of the line you just mentioned, or until the end of the entire file?

Comment: @monolith937 You read till newline character and since fscanf() fails you exit the loop

Comment: It will go until you stop reading integers, i.e. until the newline at the end of the current line or until you reach EOF. Since Steve is the 1st row of your file, it will read until the newline of this line. I gave you a +1 in your question, for balancing, but make sure you search better before asking next time. EOF is something you could easily find via google. :) @monolith937

Comment: Ah yes this is the answer  I was looking for, so `\n` is just as good as `EOF`. The problem was that most definitions I found on EOF were fairly broad

Comment: `\n` is just as good as `EOF` in our case, **they are not the same thing**, but I think you understood that already. Just remember that it is the End Of File. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The prototype for `fscanf()` is

```
int fscanf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

In your code you have

```
fscanf(in,"%s",name)
```

So the format specifier makes sure the first string in the file is read to name. I hope you know how `%s` works it reads until a space is encountered.

Now the file pointer is pointing to the next string in your file and the next string is read similarly to `surname` and next we move on to the integers which follow the strings.

```
fscanf(in,"%d",&grade);
```

Note that `fscanf()` returns number of items successfully scanned, EOF when there is an error or EOF is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can look fscanf like a function that it takes as input from a file instead of a keyboard according to what the 3rd argument is. if it is stdin it would take from keyboard. when reading from a file when it reads a space character it stops and returns the characters that it has read till the space.

Comment: actually, it is the first argument that indicates where to input is from, not the third argument.